# Como pegar uma informação específica dentro de um Json com PHP?

Tags: php, json

Tenho esse código que retorna um JSON

```
$json_file = file_get_contents("https://api.blinktrade.com/api/v1/BRL/ticker?          crypto_currency=BTC");   
$json_str = json_decode($json_file, true);
var_dump($json_str);
```

Agora, quero pegar uma informação específica dentro desse JSON, por exemplo, o valor de buy, como proceder?

Grato.

Comment: `$json_str['buy']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neste caso, pode utilizar a variável que recebe o JSON, seguida da chave que deseja exibir. No seu caso:

```
  $json_str['buy'];
```

Se dentro da chave "buy" houvesse outra, bastaria chamá-la da mesma forma

```
$json_str['buy']['outra_chave'];
```